# Efficient way of calculating average difference of array elements from array average value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, average

Is there a way to calculate the average distance of array elements from array average value, by only "visiting" each array element once? (I search for an algorithm)

Example:

```
Array : [ 1 , 5 , 4 , 9 , 6 ]
Average : ( 1 + 5 + 4 + 9 + 6 ) / 5 = 5
Distance Array : [|1-5|, |5-5|, |4-5|, |9-5|, |6-5|] = [4 , 0 , 1 , 4 , 1 ]
Average Distance : ( 4 + 0 + 1 + 4 + 1 ) / 5 = 2
```

The simple algorithm needs 2 passes.

1st pass) Reads and accumulates values, then divides the result by array length to calculate average value of array elements.

2nd pass) Reads values, accumulates each one's distance from the previously calculated average value, and then divides the result by array length to find the average distance of the elements from the average value of the array.

The two passes are identical. It is the classic algorithm of calculating the average of a set of values. The first one takes as input the elements of the array, the second one the distances of each element from the array's average value.

Calculating the average can be modified to not accumulate the values, but caclulating the average "on the fly" as we sequentialy read the elements from the array.

The formula is:

```
Compute Running Average of Array's elements
-------------------------------------------
RA[i] = E[i] {for i == 1}
RA[i] = RA[i-1] - RA[i-1]/i + A[i]/i { for i > 1 }
```

Where A[x] is the array's element at position x, RA[x] is the average of the array's elements between position 1 and x (running average).

My question is:

Is there a similar algorithm, to calculate "on the fly" (as we read the array's elements), the average distance of the elements from the array's mean value?

The problem is that, as we read the array's elements, the final average value of the array is not known. Only the running average is known. So calculating differences from the running average will not yield the correct result. I suppose, if such algorithm exists, it probably should have the "ability" to compensate, in a way, on each new element read for the error calculated as far.

Comment: you can calculate the square of the distance (l2 norm) in a single pass, but i don't know of an equivalent for the absolute difference (l1).

Comment: well, for the purpose I want it, maybe the square of the distance does the job for me. It is for graphics HLSL language. The result is something like a noise reduction filter. So, as long as noise is minimized, it will work for me :) Thanks, I will take a look!

Comment: ok, see below for formula.  hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do better than O(n log n).

Suppose the array were sorted. Then we could divide it into the elements less than the average and the elements greater than the average. (If some elements are equal to the average, that doesn't matter.) Suppose the first k elements are less than the average. Then the average distance is

D = ((x<sub>ave</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>) + (x<sub>ave</sub>-x<sub>2</sub>) + (x<sub>ave</sub>-x<sub>3</sub>) + ... + (x<sub>ave</sub>-x<sub>k</sub>) + (x<sub>k+1</sub>-x<sub>ave</sub>) + (x<sub>k+2</sub>-x<sub>ave</sub>) + ... + (x<sub>n</sub>-x<sub>ave</sub>))/n

= (-x<sub>1</sub>) + (-x<sub>2</sub>) + (-x<sub>3</sub>) + ... + (-x<sub>k</sub>) + (x<sub>k+1</sub>) + (x<sub>k+2</sub>) + ... + (x<sub>n</sub>) + (n-2k)x<sub>ave</sub>)/n

= ( [sum of elements above average] - [sum of elements below average] + (n-2k)x<sub>ave</sub>)/n

You could calculate this in one pass by working in from both ends, adjusting the limits on the (as-yet-unknown) average as you go. **This would be O(n), and the sorting is O(n logn) (and they could perhaps be done in the same operation), so the whole thing is O(n logn).**

Comment: The question firstly came up to me when I was playing with some HLSL code (shader code for graphics, like DirectX).

In this situation the array is actually the texture in memory. In fact it is a NxN area around a particular pixel with N^2 elements to firstly read to calculate the average lightness, and then re-read to calculate the average distance of each pixel's lightness to the previously calculated average. Therefore, the array (the NxN area of pixels) cannot be sorted or manipulated in any way before I first get hands on it in the shader code.

Comment: I wanted to find a way to minimize texture lookups (reading pixel values from the texture) since this operation significantly lowers performance. If I have a 5x5 kernel, I make a lookup in the texture 2*5*5 times for each pixel. If I have an input texture of 1024*768 pixels, then I have a total of 39,321,600 texture reads per frame. It's too much. I though that halving that amount would be really great, so i started to think if there is a way to calculate what I wanted in one-go, reading input values once.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with a two pass approach is that you need to reread or store the entire sequence for the second pass. The obvious improvement would be to maintain a data structure so that you could adjust the sum of absolute differences when the average value changed.

Suppose that you change the average value to a very large value, by observing a huge number. Now compare the change made by this to that caused by observing a not quite so huge value. You will be able to work out the difference between the two sums of absolute differences, because both average values are above all the other numbers, so all of the absolute values decrease by the difference between the two huge averages. This predictable change carries on until the average meets the highest value observed in the standard numbers, and this change allows you to find out what the highest number observed was.

By running experiments like this you can recover the set of numbers observed before the numbers you shove in to run the experiments. Therefore any clever data structure you use to keep track of sums of absolute differences is capable of storing the set of numbers observed, which (except for order, and cases where multiple copies of the same number are observed) is pretty much what you do by storing all the numbers seen for a second pass. So I don't think there is a trick for the case of sums of absolute differences as there is for squares of differences, where most of the information you care about is described by just the pair of numbers (sum, sum of squares).

Comment: The question may be more specific than needed. What I was actually looking for in the first place is a way to get a value that tells me how scattered (apart) are the elements of an array, by reading the array values once. Since it is within HLSL graphics code, values are in [0...255], so I expect a value from 0 to 255 (extreme cases). I think it would not be a value greater than 128 though. for instance, for values [3,5,3,5] the value would be 1 (average distance from array average is 1). for [2,6,2,6] the value would be 2 (average distance from average is 2 though in both cases average is 4)

Comment: You can calculate the variance in a single pass quite easily. The square root of this, the standard deviation, has a lot of similarities to your mean absolute deviation. There are a number of ways of doing this. The one at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#On-line_algorithm has been tuned to give good numerical accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

if the l2 norm (average distance squared) is ok then it's:

```
sqrt(sum(x^2)/n - (sum(x)/n)^2)
```

that's (square root of) the average x^2 minus the square of the average x.

it's called [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_formula_for_the_variance) (actually, the above is the square root of the variance, which is called the standard deviation, and is a typical "measure of spread").

note that this is more sensitive to outliers than the measure you originally asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Your followup described your context as HLSL reading from a texture.  If your filter footprint is a power of two and is aligned with the same power-of-two boundaries in the original image, you can use MIP maps to find the average value of the filter region.

For example, for an 8x8 filter, precompute a MIP map three levels down the MIP chain, whose elements will be the averages of each 8x8 region.  Then a single texture read from that MIP level texture will give you the average for the 8x8 region.  Unfortunately this doesn't work for sliding the filter around to arbitrary positions (not multiples of 8 in this example).

You could make use of intermediate MIP levels to decrease the number of texture reads by utilizing the MIP averages of 4x4 or 2x2 areas whenever possible, but that would complicate the algorithm quite a bit.